# Jquery & Phonegap

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

trying to get some info from my Mysql database to show up by connecting with phonegap through jquery to my PHP code..

however when I load up the page (either on my phone or on my PC) it comes up completely blank..

this is my jquery code which is in the phonegap build right before the <./body.> tag and I am including the latest jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://feedmysound.com/app/json.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var landmark = '<h1>'+item.title+'</h1>'
                + '<p>'+item.postin+'<br>'
                + item.user+'</p>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
   });
 </script>
```

and this is the php which is on the json.php:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx","xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM xxxxx WHERE postin = 'main' ORDER BY datetime DESC")or die(mysqli_error($con));

$records = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$records[] = $row;
}   

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

does anyone know whats wrong?

this is the fiddle.. not sure if thats even possible here but http://jsfiddle.net/h4dmF/9/

Kind regards

Comment: Probably a CORS problem --- It will only work once built as an app.

Comment: Is the database remote, right? You need to use an IP to connect, and the database needs to allow access from external IPs

Comment: -Ahren
The app is built aswell, nothing shows up

-Damien Pirsy
The database is a MYSQL database which the php file json.php connects to through localhost as it is loaded on this server, so for 1 I need to use IP as opposed to domain and 2 I need to make sure my database allows external access?

Comment: I'm not sure about your app but the fiddle at least was wrapped in SCRIPT tags incorrectly. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/h4dmF/10/

Comment: I made sure my database is accepting external access, as well as connecting through IP but hansvedo your last comment seemed to do it! not sure if it was the output div or the script tags but your a hero!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json.php data URL is loading up fine in a browser so there's no issue with the MySQL connection.

I'm not sure about your app but the fiddle at least was wrapped in SCRIPT tags incorrectly. Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/h4dmF/10

```
<div id="output"></div>​
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Since the app is loading data from a remote domain, you may need to use $.jsonp instead of $.ajax:
http://samcroft.co.uk/2010/loading-data-into-a-phonegap-app/

Comment: I simply chose this because you fixed it in the comments with your jsfiddle! and I can't choose my own answers :) thanks hansvedo!

Comment: cool ok, i just pulled those notes in from the comment to complete the answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

"*I'm not sure about your app but the fiddle at least was wrapped in SCRIPT tags incorrectly. Here's a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/h4dmF/10)*" – **hansvedo**

Fixed it in comments! thanks everyone who tried to help/thought about the problem!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://feedmysound.com/app/json.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var landmark = '<h1>' + item.title + '</h1>' + '<p>' + item.postin + '<br>' + item.user + '</p>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
});
```